# Fixed menu overlaps content when scrolling back to top in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-position

My site has a fixed horizontal menu. When viewed in Safari, the elements following the menu scroll underneath it when scrolling back to the top of the page from a lower position. Adding margin-top or padding-top equal to the height of the menu to the content area fixes the issue only after scrolling down, and leaves a blank space in other browsers. How can I prevent the content from going below the menu like that?

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky fixed">
  <nav class="top-bar" style="">
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="fullWidthBar bar3">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 10010;
}
.contain-to-grid {
width: 100%;
background: 
#0D42C0;
border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
}
.top-bar {
max-width: 62.5em;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
background: #0D42C0;
overflow: visible;
min-height: 45px; 
}
.bar3 {
background: 
#04297D;
}
.fullWidthBar {
max-width: 100%;
padding-top: 0px;
height: auto;
padding: 2% 0;
}
.row {
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
max-width: 62.5em;
}
```

[The site](http://www.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have a class of `fixed` switching on and off on the following `div` tag

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky fixed">
```

Judging by the way the page behaves the class `fixed` is set by a javascript handler. I would set it so then it is always present. that would fix this issue.

Comment: Yessir, that would be the cause. Good find. Thank you!